# Django all-auth Slack: Redirect URL as https instead of http and Social Network Login Failure

Tags: python, django, oauth, slack-api, django-allauth

Hi I am using [`django all-auth`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#slack) with Slack. However, I have 2 problems.

1st: the redirect URL  always goes to HTTP instead of HTTPS. E.g. I click on ***.ngrok.io/accounts/slack/login and then get redirected to `https://***.slack.com/oauth?client_id=1737791866593.2107881969061&scope=identify&user_scope=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F***.ngrok.io%2Faccounts%2Fslack%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&state=ANmZKE1CMWq7&granular_bot_scope=0&single_channel=0&install_redirect=&tracked=1&response_type=code&team=` as you can see the redirect_uri is HTTP. How can I change this in `django all-auth`?
[image: Bug description]

2nd: After manually changing it I am still not able to login as I get the error below (see picture):
[image: 2nd error]

e.g. https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#slack

Comment: I'm also trying to setup django-allauth with slack and running into your 2nd problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following allauth configuration to your `settings.py`:

```py
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
```

Comment: yes indeed, that was working I still have an error though. Are you using django-allauth with Slack in your code too?

Comment: @manfredobelugo I had the same issue with Facebook. Making the above change fixed it for me. What command are you using for ngrok? Using something like `--host-header="localhost:80"` could also make it not work.